# Take files from user in web page and pass these files to another python script

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

I am building an webpage using flask, html, css. In that webpage, there is a dropdown menu with 8 options each corresponding to an .h5 file. And there is file upload option which accepts images. Now, the the .h5 file corresponding to the selected option and the image uploaded should go to model_path and image_path respectively into a python script. And when submit button is clicked in the webpage, the python script has to execute and display the output in the same page. Is it possible? and how?

I tried writing in flask only but no result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

> Hi I think you expected like this.

```
from flask import send_file
@app.route('/upload/', methods=['POST'])
    def upload():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # FileStorage object wrapper
            file = request.files["file"]                    
            if file:
                result = model.predict(file)
            return send_file(result)
```